# Element unidentifiable in Sikuli-Selenium Webdriver : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

My application has a Upload button, clicking on which opens the local file explorer. Tried to automate the window using Sikuli. Below is the Sikuli code snippet.

```
ImagePath.setBundlePath("C:\\TempFolder\\");
String imageName = "TextBox.PNG";
Screen s = new Screen();
Match m = s.find(imageName);
m.highlight();
s.click(imageName);
```

On execution, it is failing at 
`Match m = s.find(imageName);`
and the error message is:

[image]

The snapshot of pom.xml
[image]

Comment: The message clearly says org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils not found. have you considered fixing this issue? Another question, how are you managing your libraries?

Comment: Using maven to add dependencies. Added `org.apache.commons.io` also in pom.xml.

Comment: It will be helpful, if you can share your pom.xml

Comment: @Popeye, edited the question.
Also, tried to add `jna` dependency too, but it throws error.

Comment: It looks like it should not throw the error. how do you compile? how do you execute?

Comment: It's resolved. Seems like the `jna` dependency added was not the latest version. And also, I used Sikuli IDE to capture the snapshot.